# insert the friends photos in a database in array

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
function getUserFriends(a) {
  var id=a;
  FB.api('/me/friends?fields=picture', function (response) {
    //console.log('Got friends: ', id);
    var x = y = 0;
    var photos=[];
    for (var i=0;i < response.data.length;i++) {
            photos = response.data[i].picture.data.url;
            $.post("insert_photo.php", {
            "pic": photos,
            "id":id
        }, function (data) {

        });

    }
}
```

I am using a Facebook API to call my friends friends profile pic and using a post inserting into the db , suppose if i have 500 friends , it will send the post request 500 times , now i want to store it in the array and then the post request . is it possible , if yes please tell me how

Answer (score 0):

**Getting Friends**

[v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, getting the list of friends with `/me/friends` has been removed. So, the method you are using will be [removed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions) in a few months.

But there is another option now to get the friends (basically the taggable friends) with end point `/me/taggable_friends`; but this needs to be approved first. ([Check out the complete discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m))

**Save profile pictures**

If you want to save the urls in an array and then make the post requests,  you can do that too-

```
FB.api('/me/taggable_friends', function (response) {
   var x = y = 0;
   var photos=[];
   for (var i=0;i < response.data.length;i++) {
        var user={};
        user.photo = response.data[i].picture.data.url;
        user.id = response.data[i].id;
        photos.push(user);
   }

   // at this point all the friends data have been saved in the array
   for(var i=0; i<photos.length;i++){
       $.post("insert_photo.php", {
            "pic": photos[i].photo,
            "id":photos[i].id
          }, function (data) {
             // done
       });
   }
});
```

**Or** the cleaner way-

Send the `photos` array to the php script and let php script loop through it and save to the db-

```
 $.post("insert_photo.php", {
        "data": JSON.stringify(photos)
      }, function (data) {
         // done
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you, but if you want to do only **one** POST call, you could move the $.post() outside of the for loop. And then send all the photos array as json.

For example:

```
function getUserFriends(a) {
  var id=a;
  FB.api('/me/friends?fields=picture', function (response) {
    //console.log('Got friends: ', id);
    var x = y = 0;
    // Storing all photo urls in array
    var photos=[];
    for (var i=0;i < response.data.length;i++) {
        photos.push(response.data[i].picture.data.url);
    }

    // Send photos as JSON
    $.post("insert_photo.php", {
            "pics": photos,
            "id":id
       }, function (data) {}
    );
}
```

This will send all the photos in a single POST call. You will have to update the insert_photo.php script to iterate over the "pics" param. Something like:

```
<?php
[...]
foreach (json_decode($_POST['pics']) as $pic) {
     [...]
     // You can use $pic here
     [...]
}
[...]
```